# SQL bubbling or hierarchical pattern for searching higher and higher levels

Tags: sql, hierarchy

We have company, branch, and user tables/levels. Each level has a nullable id associated with a configuration in a configuration table.  If the configuration id is null, it should return the configuration at the higher level, and there is a non nullable id associated with that higher level.  If there is no configuration associated at the highest level, it should return nothing.  One additional complication is that the configuration should have an IsDeleted value of 0.

What's a good SQL pattern for such a hierachy?  I did search for this on the web, but since I'm not sure what to even call it, so it didn't yield any useful results.

I tried the sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1815/10/0 , but I don't like the pattern I'm using.  The schema is just a bunch of tables each with one element, and the company is the only one that points to a config.
Schema:

```
-- all ids would be uniqueidentifiers
-- pks and fks are primary and foreign keys that would be.
create table all_user
(
  id int not null, -- pk
  branchid int not null, -- fk
  configID int -- fk
);
create table branch
(
  id int not null, -- pk
  companyID int not null, -- fk
  configID int -- fk
);
create table company
(
  id int not null, -- pk
  configID int -- fk
);

create table config
(
  id int not null, -- pk
  name varchar(36) not null,
  isDeleted bit default(0)
);

insert into config (id, name) values (1, 'firstConfig');
insert into company(id,configID) values (1,1);
insert into branch(id, companyID) values (1, 1);
insert into all_user(id, branchID) values(1, 1);
```

And here is the Query:

```
    declare @UserID int
select @UserID = 1

declare @uconfigID int
declare @bconfigID int
declare @cconfigID int
declare @numConfigs int
    select @numConfigs = 0  -- UPDATE (makes query work)

SELECT @uconfigID = au.configID, @bconfigID = b.configID, @cconfigID = c.configID
from all_user au 
join branch b on au.branchID = b.ID
join company c on b.companyID = c.ID
where au.ID = @UserID

if @uconfigID is not null
BEGIN
    select @numConfigs = count(*) 
    from config
    where id = @uconfigID
    and IsDeleted = 0

    if @numConfigs = 1
    BEGIN
      select *
      from config
      where id = @uconfigID
      and IsDeleted = 0
    END
END

if @numConfigs = 0 and @bconfigID is not null
BEGIN
    select @numConfigs = count(*) 
    from config
    where id = @bconfigID
    and IsDeleted = 0

    if @numConfigs = 1
    BEGIN
      select * 
      from config
      where id = @bconfigID
      and IsDeleted = 0
    END
END

if @numConfigs = 0 and @cconfigID is not null
BEGIN
    select @numConfigs = count(*) 
    from config
    where id = @cconfigID
    and IsDeleted = 0

    if @numConfigs = 1
    BEGIN
      select *
      from config
      where id = @cconfigID
      and IsDeleted = 0
    END
END
```

Also, I don't like that I'm using joins, since really I want to shortcircuit it at the first level that returns a valid (nondeleted) configuration.

Is there a better approach?  Perhaps recursive?

Thanks.